# data.table := assigning and grouping

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, assign

Working on country specific data. Need to assign and group countries into pre-defined country groups.  Wrote code as below.  Like to know if there is more efficient way to script by NOT typing each NEW country every time it comes into the database into the section of assigning into NON-CORE group?  Sounds like if else.  But don't know how to code that.

```
library(data.table)
data<- data.table(data)
setkey(data,Region.Group)
data[list(c(
  "Australia",
  "Bangladesh",
  "Cambodia",
  "Estonia",
  "Finland",
  "France",
  "India",
  "Indonesia",
  "Korea",
  "Lithuania",
  "Malaysia",
  "Middle East",
  "Norway",
  "Philippines",
  "Poland",
  "Russia",
  "Spain",
  "Sri Lanka",
  "Sweden",
  "Switzerland",
  "TAT Region",
  "Thailand",
  "Ukraine",
  "Vietnam",
  "New Zealand",
  "Israel",
  "Myanmar",
  "Pakistan",
  "Portugal",
  "Turkey",
  "Portugal")), Core:="NON-CORE"]
data[list(c(
  "Belgium",
  "Netherlands")), Core:="Benelux"]
data[list(c(
  "China Group")), Core:="China"]
data[list(c(
  "Germany")), Core:="Germany"]
data[list(c(
  "Hong Kong Group")), Core:="Hong Kong"]
data[list(c(
  "Italy")), Core:="Italy"]
data[list(c(
  "Japan")), Core:="Japan"]
data[list(c(
  "North America Central",
  "North America East",
  "North America North",
  "North America South",
  "North America West")), Core:="N.America"]
data[list(c(
  "Singapore")), Core:="Singapore"]
data[list(c(
  "Taiwan")), Core:="Taiwan"]
data[list(c(
  "United Kingdom")), Core:="UK"]
```

Comment: That's not quite reproducible, since we don't have your original "data" object, fyi. Also, I don't quite understand the problem; are you getting new countries each day? The simple solution might be to initialize `data[,Core:="NON-CORE"]` if adding countries to that list is the problem.

Comment: We only include country when there is activity in particular measuring window, say quarter 1 this year. The same country may not have any activity thus no data exists in another quarter, say 2.

Comment: Data structure is like : Region.Group Period Qty1 Qty2
Belgium 2013Q1 1.85 4
Belgium 2013Q2 0.43 1
Belgium 2013Q1 0.62 1
Belgium 2013Q2 0.86 2
Belgium 2013Q1 0.46 0
Belgium 2013Q2 0.57 1
Belgium 2013Q2 1.14 1
Belgium 2013Q1 1.23 1
Belgium 2013Q2 0.57 1
Belgium 2013Q1 1.15 1
China Group 2013Q2 0.14 0
China Group 2013Q1 1.23 2
China Group 2013Q1 0.15 0
China Group 2013Q1 0.31 0
China Group 2013Q1 0.15 0
China Group 2013Q1 0.69 1
Finland 2013Q2 0.86 5
Finland 2013Q2 0.14 0
Finland 2013Q2 0.29 0
France 2013Q2 0.71 2
France 2013Q2 0.29 0
France 2013Q2 0.29 0
Germany 2013Q2 0.14 3

Comment: Actually we are trying to re-group Region.Group into a few bigger territorial groups (higher level than Region.Group) under NEW column: Core.

Comment: Do not add additional information in the comments, add them by editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to put the country in the correct group at some point. How about a list (shortened here), where we don't bother to put NON-CORE countries:

```
coregroup <- list(
    Benelux     =   c("Belgium","Netherlands"),
    Germany     =   "Germany"
)
```

Then you can make a `data.table` out of this list

```
dt_coregroup <- data.table(
    Core=rep(names(coregroup),lapply(coregroup,length)),
    Region.Group=unlist(coregroup)
)
#       Core Region.Group
# 1: Benelux      Belgium
# 2: Benelux  Netherlands
# 3: Germany      Germany
```

and merge it back into your original data. I've put in some nonsense data and renamed it to "dt_start", because apparently "data" is already an R function.

```
dt_start <- data.table(Region.Group=c("Germany","Belgium","Australia"),Period=rep("2013Q1",3),Qty1=1:3)
setkey(dt_start,Region.Group)
setkey(dt_coregroup,Region.Group)

dt_new <- dt_coregroup[dt_start]
#    Region.Group    Core Period Qty1
# 1:    Australia      NA 2013Q1    3
# 2:      Belgium Benelux 2013Q1    2
# 3:      Germany Germany 2013Q1    1
```

Finally, in the last step, we assign any ungrouped countries to NON-CORE:

```
dt_new[is.na(Core),Core:="NON-CORE"]
#    Region.Group     Core Period Qty1
# 1:    Australia NON-CORE 2013Q1    3
# 2:      Belgium  Benelux 2013Q1    2
# 3:      Germany  Germany 2013Q1    1
```

Comment: @KFB Hi. I've rearranged things so that any country not mentioned in the "coregroup" list gets assigned to "NON-CORE" at the end. If you have clarifications to make or further questions that still fit into the original question, it is preferred that you edit them into your question (rather than only as comments or edits to answers). Thanks for the clarification, though. :)

Comment: Frank, Thanks! I m newbie to this great site.